# Why is semver and marked inlined in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[marked](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/base/common/marked/marked.js) and [semver](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/base/common/semver/semver.js) libraries are inlined in the VSCode repo.

What is the reason for it?

They seems to use old versions for them:

- semver:

  - last version: 7.5.4
  - inlined version: 5.5.0
- marked

  - last version: 11.1.1
  - inlined version: 3.0.2

Those versions have vulnerabilities: (marked: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rrrm-qjm4-v8hf / https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5v2h-r2cx-5xgj, semver: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw)